# Out of Memory : android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-appcompat, appcompatactivity

we recently switched to using AppCompatActivity instead of FragmentActivity and now some devices are randomly crashing with the following error. No idea why this is happening.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 16008012 byte allocation with 4277152 free bytes and 4MB until OOM
   at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(VMRuntime.java)
   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(BitmapFactory.java)
   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:856)
   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:675)
   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:703)
   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:733)
   at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.updateStateFromTypedArray(BitmapDrawable.java:779)
   at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.inflate(BitmapDrawable.java:741)
   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:2549)
   at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflateLayers(LayerDrawable.java:254)
   at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflate(LayerDrawable.java:164)
   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:2549)
   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:2320)
   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:4210)
   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:4089)
   at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:2005)
   at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1987)
   at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:464)
   at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.android.support.v4.content.ContextCompatApi21.getDrawable(SourceFile:3026)
   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(SourceFile:200)
   at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(SourceFile:81)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.(SourceFile:127)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.(SourceFile:147)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.(SourceFile:27)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.(SourceFile:53)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV23.(SourceFile:29)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(SourceFile:203)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(SourceFile:185)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(SourceFile:525)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:74)
   at com.dubizzle.horizontal.activities.AbstractActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:98)
   at com.dubizzle.horizontal.activities.ItemPhotoViewer.onCreate(SourceFile:68)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3207)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: It's because the file you are trying to load is big

Comment: Show code of `com.dubizzle.horizontal.activities.AbstractActivity.onCreate` and `com.dubizzle.horizontal.activities.ItemPhotoViewer.onCreate`

Comment: @TapanHP you are giving bad advises

Comment: @Divers PhotoViewer has a gallery that loads images from the web using Picasso

Comment: @SayedHassan It impossible to help you with something specific without watching on your code.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to load an image using the BitmapFactory right?

I assume that your image is too big:

> 16008012 byte allocation with 4277152 free bytes and 4MB until OOM

Your image is 16008012 but you only have 4277152 bytes free. 
Try using a smaller image.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But why did it start only after switching to AppCompatActivity. Also, there is an image gallery on that particular screen and pics are loaded from the web using picasso.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I set a rather large drawable as the windowBackground property of the activity's theme. Reducing the size of the image should fix it